# Swift: How to insert a getter in computed property to calculate a person's age

Tags: swift, return-type, computed-properties

I have written the following computed property to calculate the age of the app user:

```
var ageCalc: Int {
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let now = Date()
    let calcAge = calendar.components(.year, from: userData.birthdate, to: now, options: [])
    let age = calcAge.year
}
```

The compiler error I receive is:

"Missing return in getter expected to return 'Int'"

[image: getterError]

Adding "return age" gives a slew of errors:

[image: returnAgeCode]

[image: returnAgeError]

Comment: Check out the Swift language book for some good ways to deal with Optionals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Calendar` instead of the old `NSCalendar` you can write the property as

```
var ageCalc: Int {
    Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.year], from: userData.birthdate, to: .now).year!
}
```

Comment: This is what should be done, but note that the key is the `!` at the end.